# Function to scale byte array representing pixels

Tags: java, arrays, scale, pixel

Within Java, I have a `byte[]` array which is essentially storing color codes of pixels in a sprite with a given dimension. The issue I have is:

If I want to scale that sprite by `int scale`, how would I do it? I can figure out how to copy each element of the array `scale` times, but what I need to do is to essentially make sure each row is scaled properly, then put `scale` number of each row into the array.

Any ways you know of doing that?

EDIT:

I've tried this function, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public static byte[] scaleImage(byte[] pix, int width, int scale){
    int height = pix.length / width;
    byte[] ret = new byte[pix.length * scale * scale];
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
        if(i % scale == 0){
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
                if(j % scale == 0)ret[i * width * scale + j] = pix[(i / scale) * width + (j / scale)];
                else ret[i * width * scale + j] = ret[i * width * scale + j -1];
            }
        }
        else for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
            ret[i * width * scale + j] = ret[(i-1) * width * scale + j];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Is your data ARGB byte array?

Comment: No, they're color-codes which are interpreted by a function in another class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with int [] arrays using BufferedImage and AffineTransformOp. The advantage of this is that your data is treated as an image rather than array, so you can use different scaling algorithms, interpolation etc, non-integer scale values etc.

Example scaling a 2 x 2 image to 4 x 4

First write data into image

```
int[] rawData = new int[2 * 2 * 4]; // input is 4 int per pixel, ARGB 
BufferedImage input = new BufferedImage(2, 2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
((WritableRaster) input.getData()).setPixels(0, 0, 2, 2, rawData);
```

Scale it

```
int scale = 2;
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.scale(scale, scale);
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, null);
BufferedImage output = new BufferedImage(input.getWidth() * scale, input.getHeight() * scale, input.getType());
op.filter(input, output);
```

Pixels can then can be accessed

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output.getData().getPixels(0, 0, output.getWidth(), output.getHeight(), (int[]) null)));
```

Comment: Thing is they're not ARGB, they're just codes to be used elsewhere. If I'd set the pixels in a `BufferedImage` to that when the values aren't ARGB, just random values around 1 - 100, and then try to use `BufferedImage.getRGB()`, will that return the same value that went into it(if I I use `TYPE_INT_RGB` instead), or something else?